# is there a way to convert speed into g-force, or do you need acceleration too?

Tags: airspeed, g-forces

kind of a stupid question, just wondering.

Comment: [Calculation of the G-force](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1227/calculation-of-the-g-force) on Physics.SE

Answer (score 4):

This is a physics question, but.

Speed has no relation to g-force. One *g* is the *vertical acceleration* one feels when standing still on the Earth's surface, and is equal to –9.8 meters per second per second (an acceleration, you will notice). When one *changes one's velocity*, i.e. accelerates, one experiences a g-force acting in the opposite direction of the change in velocity: If you go faster forward, you feel a g-force pushing you backward, and vice versa. If you go faster upward, you feel a g-force pushing you downward, and vice versa.

So if one's velocity is constant there is no g-force felt other than the standard one *g* due to Earth's gravity. Note that I have used "velocity" throughout—velocity specifies both an object's speed and direction. It is possible to maintain the same speed while changing velocity, for example in an uncoordinated turn; it is also possible to keep going the same direction and change velocity by changing speed.

Now it is true that the same control inputs, when going at different speeds, will result in different changes in velocity, ergo different accelerations, ergo different experienced g-forces. Compare a fighter pilot pulling the stick back 10% while flying at 150KT with a fighter pilot pulling the stick back 10% while traveling at 500KT—quite different!